# What is the difference between tags "validity" and "validation"?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should [validity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/validity) and [validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/validation) be synonyms, or there is a difference in meaning between them?

So far (07th, July, 2013):
[validity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/validity) was used 16 times on CV and [validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/validation) 69 times.

Edit 1:

This is a first suggestion for tag wiki excerpt given the answers of @gung and @Glen_b.

<s>**Validity** is the extent to which a concept, conclusion or measurement is well-founded and corresponds accurately to the real world. The validity of a measurement tool is considered to be the degree to which the tool measures what it claims to measure.</s> DO NOT use this tag for "validation" model purposes.

**Validation** is the process of deciding whether the numerical results quantifying hypothesized relationships between variables, obtained from regression analysis, are in fact acceptable as descriptions of the data.  <s>DO NOT use this tag for asking if it is valid ("validity") to use a certain test, measurement or analysis.</s>

References: [Wikipedia 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_(statistics)), [Wikipedia 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_model_validation)

<s>Please, manifest the suggestion with upvotes, downvotes, additional comments, additional answers (we have right now 17-July-2013: question -1, @gung +9, Glen_b +6).</s>

Edit 2 (status-completed):

The tag wiki excerpts were edited and approved according to modifications suggested by @gung and @Glen_b. See them [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/validity) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/validation).
Further improvements can be suggested directly on the tag wiki excerpts pages or with the opening of a new thread.

Thank's.

Comment: -1 / +1; I think the excerpt for `[validity]` is fine & shouldn't be changed. Your suggestion for the excerpt for `[validation]` seems fine; I'd say you should go ahead & edit.

Comment: @gung. Thank's for replying. And what about the part of "do not use this tag for `validation` model purposes". Do you think it would be useful to aware askers about "validation" tag?

Comment: I think your proposal for the `[validation]` tag is fine; you could include that part as well.

Comment: +1 as it stands, however I think the later part of the final sentence of `validation` "*for asking if it is valid ("validity") to use a certain test, measurement or analysis.*" doesn't quite relate to the sense of 'validity' being conveyed in the first tag, which is about the relationship between tests or instruments (like a particular IQ test) and the real world (i.e. 'How can we be confident this IQ test actually tells us about something real?' is a question relating to validity). The sentence gives the impression the `validity` tag is about when it's okay to do t-tests. ... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... I suggest that the wording be altered to "*for discussing validity of a measurement or instrument -- such as that it measures what it purports to.*" or something similar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think these should be synonyms:

- **Validity** is a *property* of something.  For example, it can be a [property of a measurement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_%28statistics%29)--that it measures what it purports to measure.

  This is what the tag wiki excerpt currently indicates, and that seems to be how it's being used (*note: I edited one question where* `validity` *was being used in a different sense*).  Nonetheless, there are other possibilities, such as a property of an *experiment* (e.g., internal & external validity) or a property of a *model*; if need be, we could create additional tags to denote these and ensure the excerpts do a good job of guiding people in their use.  At present, this doesn't seem to be necessary, though.
- **Validation** is a *process*.  Examples might be [cross-validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-validation/info) or [sensitivity analyses](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/sensitivity-analysis/info).  (I'm sure there are more.)

However, I do think we need to add a tag wiki excerpt for [validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/validation) to guide people in its appropriate use.  We simply need to figure out here what that should be.

Comment: I agree with this - they shouldn't be synonyms, and if they're being used as such, they're being misused.

Answer (score 6):

Usage of ['validity'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_%28statistics%29) tends mostly to refer to the sense in used in psychometrics, education and other social sciences and often refers to specific tests or instruments to measure some particular thing ("IQ-test validity"). 'Validation' is usually used in a different (though not entirely unrelated) sense relating to the properties of particular statistical models - model-validation, predictive-validation, cross-validation.

While occasionally they're used to talk about the same thing (like when a education researcher talks about *validation* of an instrument or someone who has just done some model validation talks about model-validity), usually the two are used quite differently.

As such I *don't* think these should be synonyms.